# Can't Subscribe to Nodes RosSharp C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ros

I cannnot subscribe to any topics using RosSharp. I am working entirely locally-on the same machine. I am fairly certain I have the right uri with the right port and cannot get any communication. I am running ROS through Win-ROS: https://ros-win.visualstudio.com/_git/ros-win?path=%2Fdoc%2FSetup.md&version=GBmaster

On my local Windows host machine, I am running `roscore` and publishing a node with:
`rostopic pub -r 10 /testtopic std_msgs/String "whatever"`.

I'm able to run a subscriber from the command prompt with `rostopic echo /testtopic` and receive the correct data back, but I cannot get this subscriber to work in Unity. I'm expecting SubscriptionHandler to at least be called. This is the code I'm trying to replicate: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/blob/a45e847f96d7dd1a7859dd9595e05ef27b27b5c3/Libraries/RosBridgeClientTest/RosSocketTests.cs

Below is my code attached to a GameObject, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using RosSharp.RosBridgeClient;
using std_msgs = RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.Messages.Standard;

public class BasicROS : MonoBehaviour {

    public string uri = "ws://18.40.26.172:11311";
    private RosSocket rosSocket;
    string subscriptionId = "";

    void Start () {
        rosSocket = new RosSocket(new 
        RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.Protocols.WebSocketNetProtocol(uri)); // 10.189.42.225:9090
        Subscribe("/testtopic");
    }

    public void Subscribe(string id)
    {
        subscriptionId  = rosSocket.Subscribe<std_msgs.String>(id, SubscriptionHandler);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForKey());     
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitForKey()
    {
        Debug.Log("Press any key to close...");

        while (!Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("Closed");
       // rosSocket.Close();
    }

    private void SubscriptionHandler(std_msgs.String message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Message received!");
        Debug.Log(message.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52977500/edit) your question and include any relevant log messages you are getting and where you are expecting certain log messages that are not being printed.

Comment: Are Unity and `roscore` running on the same machine? Are you testing `rostopic` on the same machine? What command(s) are you using to start `roslaunch`?

Comment: Unity and roscore are running on the same machine. Rostopic was tested on the same machine also. I am not using roslaunch, I am publishing using rostopic pub -r 10 /testtopic std_msgs/String "whatever". I simply want to publish from the command prompt and subscribe within Unity. Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you running ros via WSL, like in [this tutorial](https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this writing, ros-win doesn't support rosbridge, which is the ros-websocket bridge that rosSharp can communicate with. If you must use ros-win and use RosSharp to do websocket communication in unity, then you will need to wait or write your own port of rosbridge.

If you can replace ros-win with [ros on WSL](https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows), then you can do the following:

Install the ros-websocket bridge suite. (Note: desktop-full does not include this, so be sure you actually get this package)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<rosdistro>-rosbridge-suite
```

e.g.,

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite
```

Run it with `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` in order for web socket messages to reach the ros network.

Doing that will create a websocket listener on port `9090`, so you need to change your uri to use port `9090`.

Also, you may want to use `localhost`, i.e., `uri = "ws://localhost:9090";`, to avoid routing issues.

Comment: Do you know whether Windows supports rosbridge_server, when I try running that command. I get:  [rosbridge_websocket.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rosbridge_server] nor is [rosbridge_server] a launch file name.

Comment: @RickyAvina I edited my answer to include instructions on how to install rosbridge, which should work if you are using WSL to run ros on Windows. I also had to add in that `9090` is the websocket port you need to use in your `uri`.

Comment: I am not using WSL to run ROS. I am using ROS-Win https://ros-win.visualstudio.com/_git/ros-win?path=%2Fdoc%2FSetup.md&version=GBmaster

Comment: @RickyAvina ros-win [doesn't list](https://ros-win.visualstudio.com/_git/ros-win?path=%2Fdoc%2FPortingStatus.md&version=GBmaster) rosbridge-suite as something it has ported, so that doesn't seem like an option. If you must use ros-win, it seems like you will need to make your own ros-websocket bridge if you want to proceed with websocket communication from unity.

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm, the problem was that ros-websocket bridge is not yet supported on WSL, so I ended up using a 2 computer system. One Linux, one Windows (for Unity).

Comment: The answer doesn't work for me unfortunately. I opened a new question here: https://answers.ros.org/question/375225/rosbridge_websocketlaunch-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-rosbridge_server-nor-is-rosbridge_server-a-launch-file-name/

Comment: @trusktr Are you sure you did `sudo apt-get install ros-<rosdistro>-rosbridge-suite`? From the linked question it looked like you did not follow that step. I think you may have downvoted this answer due to a misunderstanding. I can edit this answer emphasize that `ros-<rosdistro>-desktop-full`  isn't sufficient if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was mistaken in that "desktop-full" doesn't come with everything. The word "full" was misleading. It won't let me upvote unless you edit the answer. I suppose you can add or remove a punctuation or space somewhere.

Comment: @trusktr I included a note, please try to upvote now :)